# Can you mix keras.layers output with tensorflow operations?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, tensorflow2.0

I know that output of keras layers (like `keras.layers.Dense()`) produce so-called 'keras tensors'. Also, there are 'tensorflow tensors' that are produced by tensorflow operations (like `tf.reduce_sum()`).

Some functionality can be delivered by only one of those approaches, so it is obvious that I will have to **mix them** sometimes to do the calculation. In my opinion, mixing keras layers code with tf ops looks far from beatiful but thats another topic.

**My question is** - is it doable to mix keras layers and tensorflow ops? And will there be any problems related to mixing keras and tensorflow tensors that they produce?

---

Lets consider an example of custom class, don't look deep into the calculation, it makes no sense. The point is to show what I'm talking about.

```
class Calculation(layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, units):
        super().__init__()
        self.units = units
        self.conv3d = layers.Conv3D(units, kernel_size=3, strides=2)
        self.norm = layers.LayerNormalization(units)
    
    def call(self, x):
        x = activations.gelu(x)
        x = self.norm(x)  # keras layer
        x = tf.transpose(x, (0, 4, 1, 2, 3))
        x = self.conv3d(x)  # keras layer
        x = tf.transpose(x, (0, 2, 3, 4, 1))
        x = tf.reshape(x, (-1, 1, 2 * self.units))
    
        return x
```

---

Another example, this time not inside custom layer:

```
encoder_input = keras.Input(shape=(28, 28, 1), name="img")
x = layers.Conv2D(16, 3, activation="relu")(encoder_input)
x = layers.Conv2D(32, 3, activation="relu")(x)
x = layers.MaxPooling2D(3)(x)
x = layers.Conv2D(32, 3, activation="relu")(x)
x = tf.einsum('...ijk->...jik', x)  # tensorflow op, just swap height and width for no reason
x = layers.Conv2D(16, 3, activation="relu")(x)
```

---

I know that there is such thing as `keras.layers.Lambda` layer, but sometimes I need to use like **90%** of tensorflow ops and only **10%** of calculations done by keras layers (because there is no tf op alternative and I don't want to implement my own every time). In that case using lambda layer makes little sense.

Is there a good approach for writing complex models (where implementation lays beyond just stacking keras existing layers) in tensorflow 2.X?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMO, it actually does not matter how you mix `Tensorflow` operations with `Keras` layers as long as you preserve the batch dimension and generally the tensor shape. You might want to, for example, wrap the `tf` operations inside `Lambda` layers to set some meta-data like the names, but that depends on your taste:

```
import tensorflow as tf

encoder_input = tf.keras.Input(shape=(28, 28, 1), name="img")
x = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(16, 3, activation="relu")(encoder_input)
x = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, 3, activation="relu")(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(3)(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, 3, activation="relu")(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.Lambda(lambda x: tf.einsum('...ijk->...jik', x), name='Einsum')(x)  # tensorflow op, just swap height and width for no reason
x = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(16, 3, activation="relu")(x)
model = tf.keras.Model(encoder_input, x)
print(model.summary())
```

```
Model: "model_1"
_________________________________________________________________
 Layer (type)                Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
 img (InputLayer)            [(None, 28, 28, 1)]       0         
                                                                 
 conv2d_4 (Conv2D)           (None, 26, 26, 16)        160       
                                                                 
 conv2d_5 (Conv2D)           (None, 24, 24, 32)        4640      
                                                                 
 max_pooling2d_1 (MaxPooling  (None, 8, 8, 32)         0         
 2D)                                                             
                                                                 
 conv2d_6 (Conv2D)           (None, 6, 6, 32)          9248      
                                                                 
 Einsum (Lambda)             (None, 6, 6, 32)          0         
                                                                 
 conv2d_7 (Conv2D)           (None, 4, 4, 16)          4624      
                                                                 
=================================================================
Total params: 18,672
Trainable params: 18,672
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
None
```

For example, if you use `tf.reduce_sum` with `axis=0`, you lose the batch dimension (`None`), which is problematic for a `Keras` model:

```
import tensorflow as tf

encoder_input = tf.keras.Input(shape=(28, 28, 1), name="img")
x = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(16, 3, activation="relu")(encoder_input)
x = tf.reduce_sum(x, axis=0)
model = tf.keras.Model(encoder_input, x)
print(model.summary())
```

```
Model: "model_4"
_________________________________________________________________
 Layer (type)                Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
 img (InputLayer)            [(None, 28, 28, 1)]       0         
                                                                 
 conv2d_12 (Conv2D)          (None, 26, 26, 16)        160       
                                                                 
 tf.math.reduce_sum_1 (TFOpL  (26, 26, 16)             0         
 ambda)                                                          
                                                                 
=================================================================
Total params: 160
Trainable params: 160
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
None
```

Comment: Thank you, what if dimensions are not preserved (others than batch) - is there still a way? Do I have do something like set_shape() to explicitly hint tensorflow and keras to adjust?

Comment: Take a look at my updated answer. The other dimensions are not the problem. There are many ways to get the batch dimension again, but you should definitely avoid losing the batch dimension.

Comment: I see, I just edited my comment, what I mean is some tf op that would mess with my other dimensions (e.g. from (None, 6, 6, 32) it will become (None, 10, 4, 32), lets assume batch size is untouched) - will keras layers handle that properly?

Comment: Yes it will but obviously it depends on the layer. You decide what output shape you want after a `tf` operation.